# For loop to plot a series of boxplots side by side

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have a dataframe with three variables:

```
df <- data.frame(
  level = rep(c(2,2,1,1,0,0),3),
  names = c(rep("name1",6),rep("name2",6),rep("name3",6)),
  values = c(rnorm(6)-1, rnorm(6), rnorm(6)+1)
)
```

Now I'd like to plot for each level in `df$names` the distribution of `df$values` over `df$level` in a `for` loop. While this `for`loop does plot the desired boxplots, it plots them all in the same frame rather than, as expected, side by side:

```
for(i in unique(df$names)){
  par(new=T)
  boxplot(df[df$names==i,]$values ~ df[df$names==i,]$level)
}
```

How can I change the code so that the boxplots for each `df$names` are shown side by side?

Comment: Maybe use ggplot2 with facets, instead of forloop?

Comment: probably this is what you want: `boxplot(df$values ~ df$level+df$names)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *ggplot2*:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(level), values)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(.~names)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're very close

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

for(i in unique(df$names)){
  boxplot(df[df$names==i,]$values ~ df[df$names==i,]$level)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, that's useful. Ideally, the boxplots should all be in the same frame. How can that be achieved?

Comment: See P. Paccioretti's comment on your original post